# Regex ParsleyJS not working

Tags: html, regex, firefox, parsley.js

I'm trying to exclude any reference of <%= or %>.  It works okay if it is used just before any text, but if I use it after any text it doesn't work.

Example: If I type in **<% this is a test**, it works.  But if I type in **This is a test <%=request.** It doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?  Here is my code.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" placeholder="Your name" 
  data-parsley-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-'_]/g" required/>
```

Comment: First of all, remove `/.../g`, try `data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-'_]+$"`

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use both anchors, quantify your character class with `+` and remove regex delimiters:

```
data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-'_]+$"
```

See the [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ytpea64/).

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9-'_]+` - 1 or more chars defined in the range(s)/set
- `$` - end of string.